# Is possible to use Selenium with Python, for Electron apps?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, electron, ui-automation

I am pretty new to the Selenium testing with Electron apps; I know how to use Python to drive Chrome via the webdriver, and how to use Selenium IDE on Firefox, but I am having trouble to find a good source of info.

So far I have an app made with Electron, and I would like to use Selenium to drive it and automate the basics. I did some research and most of the results were using node.js, which I do not know at all. I would like to use Python, so before moving on a whole different language, I would like to ask to a bigger audience, if there is something already to do Selenium testing with Python, on Electron apps

In particular, how do you assign the variable that will contain the electron app? with the browser I would say

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver')
```

but this won't make sense for an electron app.

Answer (score 2):

I did find a way to catch the application.

You need to download Chromedriver; and run it on a port that you like(example: 8765).

Then you can access the application written via Electron, in Python using

```
from selenium import webdriver

    remote_app = webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(
                 command_executor='http://localhost:8765',
                 desired_capabilities = {'chromeOptions':{ 'binary': '/myapp'}},
                 browser_profile=None,
                 proxy=None,
                 keep_alive=False)
```

Then you can access the DOM elements on the app as usual. Not sure if it will work on Windows, OSX and Linux, will have to try.

Comment: For me the above call is a blocking call, was this the same case for you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with driver options and capabilities. 
You need to set binary path and you should add Arguments on options.

Binary path is your electron application path under project directory in '.bin'.
Argument path is your project's main directory.

For example : 
Let's say, your project under home directory and named 'ElectronProject'

Binart path is '/Users/Home/ElectronProject/node_modules/.bin/electron'
Argument Path is '/Users/Home/ElectronProject'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. you can refer the documentation @ https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver